# Cmake: Error loading function, subdirectory dependencies

Tags: c++, c++11, cmake

I'm entirely new to cmake and none of the similar questions on stack overflow have seemed to help with my issue.

I have several small components which can act as standalone applications and another one which uses several of these small components.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
project-dir
|--face-detect 
|--full-preprocessing
```

The project in full-preprocessing uses face-detect as a component.

in project-dir I have a CMakeLists.txt with:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_subdirectory(face-detect)
add_subdirectory(full-preprocessing)
```

in face-detect I have a CMakeLists.txt with:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
project(face_detect)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(face_detect_source_files face_detect.cpp face_detect.hpp)
add_library(face_detect_lib STATIC ${face_detect_source_files})

add_executable(face_detect run_face_detect.cpp face_detect.cpp)
target_link_libraries(face_detect ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Then in full-preprocessing I have a CMakeLists.txt with:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
project(full_preprocessing)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_executable(full_preprocessing full_preprocessing.cpp)
target_link_libraries(full_preprocessing ${OpenCV_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(full_preprocessing face_detect_lib)
```

All of the OpenCV parts definitely work and face-detect works as a standalone application (with a separate file for main). But when I run full_preprocessing I get the message "--(!)Error Loading" when the function in face-detect is called. Any clues?

Comment: What is the exact error message? What is target platform and compiler?

Comment: This does not look like a problem with cmake, as long as it compiles. The error you get may be specific to your application or OpenCV.

Comment: "--(!)Error loading" is the exact error message :/

Comment: @dragn it seems to me that it should be a linking problem of sorts.... I'm not quite sure how the entire linking process is working since I'm using cmake. I'm certain that opencv is not the issue, both of these files worked fine as standalone applications before I tried using cmake to link them together.

Comment: don't you need to `target_link_libraries(face_detect_lib ${OpenCV_LIBS})` in your face-detect CMakeLIsts.txt?

Comment: @user3288829 I tried adding that after add_library(face_detect_lib STATIC ${face_detect_source_files}) but I still get Error Loading. I may indeed need that line though. I'm going to try and read the cmake docs some more.

Comment: what compiler are you using? You may want to run it with verbose output (i.e. `make -v` for g++) and check your link lines to ensure the linking is really the issue.

Comment: I'm using g++ 4.8.4. I ran make with --debug=v and I can't find anything that looks wrong. It seems to find all of the files for face_detect_lib.

Comment: Okay, I solved the problem. It wasn't related to linking, it was related to some path issues in the code. Thanks for your help in debugging!